# Having a problem running go e-charts components package and saying that (*charts.Line does not implement components.Charter)

Tags: go, echarts

I am trying to use the go e-charts library and was able to get everything working except for the components package. I am getting the error

`cannot use dataChart(*n) (value of type *charts.Line) as type components.Charter in argument to page.AddCharts:     *charts.Line does not implement components.Charter (wrong type for GetAssets method) have GetAssets() "vendor/github.com/go-echarts/go-echarts/v2/opts".Assets want GetAssets() "github.com/go-echarts/go-echarts/v2/opts".Assets`

but all I did was copy over the code example from their repo so I'm not sure why it is saying this is invalid now. I believe it has something to do with the package download for my go project but the go get worked fine for all the other packages just not component.

I've tried multiple go gets of e-charts and requiring it in my go.mod

Comment: Your instance of `*charts.Line` is referencing a *vendored* type. While the `componens.Charter` is referencing a non-vendored type. Notice the two different package paths of the `GetAssets() "[package-path]".Assets` method mentioned in the error, that's your problem.